# Invoke MS Access Query which calls a VBA Function in a Module from Delphi ADO Component

Tags: vba, function, delphi, ms-access, delphi-2010

I created a function in an MS Access Module, let's say `Calculate(A, B)`.

I also created a Query in MS Access to use this function, let's say:

```
UPDATE aTable 
SET aField = Calculate(bField, cField)
```

How can I invoke the query, since I tried using: `adoConnection.Execute`, `adoTable`, `adoQuery`, `adoCommand`, and `StoredProcedure`, all reject it with the message

> Undefined function Calculate in expression

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you @Lee Mac for your edit. I thought there was an AI fixing automatically. LOL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.

Queries using user-defined VBA functions can only be executed by the Access Application object, and only through the `DoCmd.OpenQuery` and `DoCmd.RunSQL` methods.

Instead, use COM and the Access Application object to automate the task. Do note this will cause considerable overhead. Or, when possible, do the calculation in the SQL clause.

They're not available through ODBC or OLEDB, thus not available in ADO.

If the full version of Access (not runtime version or database engine) isn't available, you unfortunately can't run queries that use user-defined VBA functions.

Comment: Ok. Actually I can do the calculation from delphi by iterating each record. But it will take eons to complete due to huge data. I tried to do the calculation in SQL clause, but it is too complex to implement in a sql query. 

Actually the function will calculate a short string in a field with format hh:mm:ss and convert it in total seconds. 00:01:01 will return 61, and so on. After that I need to put a value based on the seconds. I need to compare two fields with that format, and put in another field an integer mark. If a < b then c is 1, if a < b * 1.1 then c is 2, and so on.