# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Undefined function 'ConcatRelated' in expression

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, oledb

I'm working on a c# winform software, connecting to local MS Access db (.mdb)

Connection string used is `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=db.mdb` and it's kinda considered a requirement, Ace is not an option.

I'm trying to use the function `ConcatRelated` but keep encountering error:
`System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Undefined function 'ConcatRelated' in expression.`

My query below:

```
string carColumnsAndTable = "SELECT c.Id, cust.CustomerName as InsuredName, c.CarPlate as VehicleNo, c.CarMake as Make, c.CarModel as Model, c.CarYear as VehicleYear, c.CarCc as CC, c.CarChasisNumber as Chasis, c.CarEngineNumber as EngineNumber,  "
    + "ConcatRelated('d.DebtorName', 'CarDebtor cd left join Debtor d on cd.DebtorId = d.Id', 'cd.CarId = ' & [c.Id]) as Debtor "
    + "FROM ((Car as c) left join Customer as cust on c.CustomerId = cust.Id) ";
```

And function setup as in screenshot below:

[image]

Query works fine in ms access:

[image]

Anyone got any clue on what I should do to resolve this?

Comment: I don't think you an call VB functions like this from outside Access.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53479165/7296893). You're unfortunately all out of luck. You can concatenate related fields by using a stored crosstab (pivot) query, concatenating the fields, and joining that to your query, or by using a separate nonstored crosstab query and joining them using LINQ

Comment: ugh that's sad, have to do it another way then.. thank you guys..